# missing right parenthesis in case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

case statement return missing parenthesis when there is no parenthesis needed

changed it to include in the where clause but getting the same error

```
select tbraccd_pidm, tbraccd_term_code        
from tbraccd 
where (tbraccd_term_code = case tbraccd_term_code
    when (substr(tbraccd_term_code,5,1) = '3') 
        then tbraccd_term_code IN ('201931', '201941') 
        else tbraccd_term_code                         
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks wrong at the first sight. If I understood what you meant to do, then it would look like this:

```
select tbraccd_pidm, tbraccd_term_code        
from tbraccd 
where tbraccd_term_code = case when substr(tbraccd_term_code, 5, 1) = '3' then ('201931', '201941') 
                               else tbraccd_term_code                         
                          end
```

Although it looks *prettier*, it will fail for exactly the same reason as yours, no difference. Why? Because you can't use IN that way; CASE won't allow it. If it were e.g.

```
case when substr(tbraccd_term_code, 5, 1) = '3' then '201931'
```

then it would be OK. But, obviously, you need both values.

I don't have your table nor data, so I'll switch to Scott's sample EMP and DEPT tables, trying to illustrate what you might try to do.

First, a query that mimics yours. SQL*Plus will show what's wrong with it (note the asterisk `*` sign below line #5):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.deptno in case when substr(e.ename, 1, 1) = 'S' then (10, 20)
  4                         else 30
  5                    end;
where e.deptno in case when substr(e.ename, 1, 1) = 'S' then (10, 20)
                                                                *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

How to rewrite it so that it works? For example, like this:

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename, e.job
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.deptno in (select e1.deptno from emp e1
  4                     where e1.deptno in (10, 20)
  5                       and substr(e.ename, 1, 1) = 'S'   --> this is the 1st CASE's WHEN
  6                    )
  7     or (    e.deptno = 30
  8         and substr(e.ename, 1, 1) <> 'S'                --> 2nd CASE's WHEN
  9        );

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN
      7900 JAMES      CLERK

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually  i had to get enames --case when substr(e.name,1,1) ='S' then substr(e.name,1,1) in ('S','R') else ename. when ename starts with 'S' get all enames that start with S and R else return ename. i am trying to achieve this in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS QUERY**

```
SELECT TBRACCD_PIDM, TBRACCD_TERM_CODE
  FROM TBRACCD
 WHERE TBRACCD_TERM_CODE =
           CASE TBRACCD_TERM_CODE
              WHEN SUBSTR (TBRACCD_TERM_CODE, 5, 1) = '3'
                 THEN TBRACCD_TERM_CODE IN ('201931', '201941')
              ELSE TBRACCD_TERM_CODE
           END
```